# Image is not displayed in android application

Tags: android

I have an android application in which I have some images. after encryption the image is not displayed in the mobile phone but it works well in emulator. My images are in drawable folder. In emulator it worke but when I installed the apk on mobile it don't work.
can anyone tell me the answer.

Thanks

```
wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    if (check_lang.equals("Marathi")) {
        getstr = getResources().getResourceEntryName(
                Marathi_Arati_ID_Array[imageIds[currentIndex]]);
        String data = "<body><center>" + "<img align="+"middle"+" src=\"" + getstr + ".png"
                + "\"/></center></body>";
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", data,
                "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    } else if (check_lang.equals("Hindi")) {
        getstr = getResources().getResourceEntryName(
                Hindi_Arati_ID_Array[imageIds[currentIndex]]);
    String data = "<center><body>" + "<img align="+"middle"+" src=\"" + getstr + ".jpg"
                + "\"/></body></center>";
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", data,
                "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    }
```

Comment: show us what you have tried.. :)

Comment: post your some code here

Comment: this is exactly what i am doing i am showing images in webview

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
`webview.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

Answer (score 0):

Your Base Url is off.

try this one and copy the image you want to use to the assets folder.

wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

And reference it as AndroidLeamer suggested